# C++ Plugin for QML, cannot see properties on C++ instance

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qml

I wrote a C++ plugin that exposes a C++ `MyCppClass` for QML. The `Q_INVOKABLE` functions work, but I cannot "see" any `Q_PROPERTY` properties for the *same* instance.

Assume a trivial `MyCppClass`:

```
class MyCppClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
  MyCppClass();
  virtual ~MyCppClass();
  Q_INVOKABLE void myInvokeFunc();
  int value();
  void setValue(int i);
signals:
  void valueChanged(int);
private:
  int m_iValue;  
};
```

Example QML use:

```
// FILE: MyQml.qml
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import MyCppPlugin 1.0

Item {
  MyCppClass {      //<==OK
     id: myClass    //<==OK
     value: 42      //<==QML LOAD ERROR
  }

  Button {
    text: "Hello"
    onClicked: {
      myClass.myInvokeFunc()   //<==OK
    }
}
```

What's going on:

- **SUCCESS**:  C++ Plugin loads through QML "import"
- **SUCCESS**:  Instantiating a C++ object in QML
- **SUCCESS**:  Calling `Q_INVOKABLE` function from QML
- **FAIL**:  Accessing any properties in QML from that *same* C++ object (QML fails to load, error:  *"Cannot assign to non-existent property "value"*") .... assigning/binding fails to load the QML file, and "reading" any property results in "undefined")

This doesn't make sense to me **(Qt 5.1.1, Win7)**.  The plugin loads, the C++ object is instantiated, the `Q_INVOKABLE` function works, but I apparently cannot "see" any `Q_PROPERTY` properties.

**QUESTION**:  **What are the possible scenarios where `Q_INVOKABLE` works on an instance, but `Q_PROPERTY` properties are still unavailable for that *same* instance?**

Answer (score 0):

I use Win 7 Qt 5.1.1 too and I have not problem with Q_PROPERTY.

Maybe a problem with yours functions implementation (like infinite loop for changed signal) ?
Or you have multiple build of your plugin and use the wrong ?

If problem is not that, you can try to create MyCppClass object in C++ and explore it with meta-objets fonctions (in particular QObject::dynamicPropertyNames or QMetaObject::propertyCount/property) to get the properties list

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are not properly registering your class in Qt meta object system. It is usually done by `qmlRegisterType` or similar methods.